# Early Modern English second person present tense when verb ends with ‑st

Tags: verbs, early-modern-english, conjugation

In Early Modern English you normally would add *‑st* or *‑est* to verbs to conjugate them to the second person singular indicative tense (past and present), but what do you do for verbs that already end in *‑st* or *‑est*? Would you just add another *‑est*?

For example:

- you jest > thou jestest
- you jested > thou jestedst
- you rest > thou restest
- you rested > thou restedst

Doing this makes the words really hard to say, especially with the past tense, so is there an exception for words like these?

Comment: I think in Early Modern English you add "st" or "est" for second person singular indicative of the present  or past tense only. Back then you'd still say "Open the door for me", not "*Openest the door for me".

In Old English it's different; one would say "þu etst" ("Thou eatst") and "þu ǣte" ("Thou ate"), not "þu *ǣtest".

Comment: Right, sorry I didn't specify indicative, but the question still stands.

Comment: I don’t see how something like _thou jestest_ is any harder to say than something like current English _the fastest_, which is structurally exactly identical, or verbs in /z/ that still add /əz/ (_rise_ -> _he rises_). The past tense _thou jestedst_ is tougher, but would also be quite rare—after all, there aren’t that many verbs that end in _-st_. I can’t seem to find any sources for this, but it seems logical to me, since _-st_ and _-əst_ were in quite free variation for a long time, that a past tense form like _thou jestedst_ would be more or less automatically replaced by _thou jestedest_.

Comment: It's only *-edst* which is difficult to say now, and that's probably because it's not very common. There's no difference really between *jestedst* and *endedst*. Or *anointedst:* see Gen 31:13 KJV.

Comment: Would it really be pronounced *-edst* or would it be *-edzd* instead? English normally assimilates voicing like that.

Comment: Another example is "to best", as in "thou bestest me each time we compete".  The word "bestest" is used occasionally today as a joking version of "best".  It's not that difficult to say.

Comment: @curiousdannii: not always, though: there are words like "width" or "breadth" that have "d" followed by a voiceless consonantal suffix. (For me, there is retrogressive voicing assimilation such that /d/ becomes [t] in these two words; but this also seems possible for *-edst*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "thou dost jest", "thou didst jest" etc. These are equally correct but not so hard on the unaccustomed tongue.